# Phonenumber lookup API to get Spam score

Tags: android, android-dialer

I'm working on an Android Dialer App and I need to know whether the incoming call phone number is a spam/robocall. Is there any Android SDK or platform available which can provide me that info? I need to show to the user that it is a spam call to warn user before he lift the phone call.

Note: I'm looking for a SDK provider who has large database of phone numbers which can give the spam score of a given phone number. (Truecaller is not providing any such API)

Answer (score 0):

use

```
getCallerDisplayName() 
getCallerNumberVerificationStatus()
```

Refer [CallerNumberVerificationStatus](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telecom/Call.Details#getCallerNumberVerificationStatus())